# How do we implement leader selection for multiple replicas Acitve-Standby(High Availability) with sidecar pattern

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-pod

How to make one only application pod as the leader node out of 2 replicas. When i start the pod with two replicas using load balancer it just starts. But i want to have an approach only one should be active and other should be standby. In case if Active gets down, standby has to make it as active in kubernetes

Comment: aren't you using readiness and liveness probes ? if your app get failed due to any issue it will auto restart on probes fail condition.

Comment: may be you can use to pod lifecycle hooks and ivoke some API to start new container or POD but in that case downtime will be there. better way is to run multiple pods and load balancing will be auto managed from service layer to pod layer.

Comment: @harsh I want two replicas to start but only one pod has to be leader and running.. it is like active standby mode in high availability